# Under which conditions will windowing with a rectangular window intime always lead oscillations in the spectrum?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, convolution, window-functions

I'm going through some conceptual questions about windowing signals. I came across the following:

> Assume a  sinusoidal signal -  under which conditions  will windowing  with a rectangular  window intime always lead oscillations in the spectrum?  And under which conditions not?

### My own answer

> We multiply a $\sin(t)$ with a rect window in the time domain. This becomes a convolution of an impulse and a $\text{sinc}$ function in the frequency domain.

> If the signal is in continuous time, then the spectrum of the signal is not periodic and we will only get one convolution of an impulse and a $\text{sinc}$ function. So some oscillations in frequency domain, but not periodic.

> If the signal is in discrete time (we have sampled it), then the spectrum of the signal is periodic. Thus, we will get infinitely many convolutions of an impulse with $\text{sinc}$ function. So forever oscillating spectrum.

And I was wondering if this is the answer they want. Because it feels like the question wants me to look at some properties of the window and the sine-wave. **So my question is** am I answering this conceptual question correctly?

### Edit

I tried to write some MATLAB code to check with Richard's answer but I can't seem to get the right thing:

[image]

```
fs = 100;
t = 0:1/fs:2-1/fs;
x = sin(2*pi*t*2);
k = [ones(100,1);zeros(100,1)];
x2 = x'.*k;
plot(t,x2)
X2 = fft(x2);

%Plotting
P2 = abs(X2/200);
P1 = P2(1:200/2+1);
P1(2:end-1) = 2*P1(2:end-1);
f = fs*(0:(200/2))/200;
plot(f,P1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question, as written, is ambiguous. Instead of "sinusoidal signal" the question's author should have written either "continuous sinusoidal signal" or "discrete sinusoidal signal".

For a windowed continuous sinusoidal signal or a discrete sinusoidal signal containing a noninteger number of cycles, the spectrum will have a main lobe and oscillating sidelobes. For a real-valued discrete sinusoidal signal containing exactly an integer number of cycles, the spectrum will have only two nonzero valued spectral samples (no main lobe and no oscillating sidelobes).

Comment: Hey Richard thank you for your answer. I have updated the question, because I can't seem to replicate what you describe. I have windowed a sine-wave after 2 cycles, but the spectrum doesn't look like you describe it. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: @Carl You plotted the positive-frequency range of the spectral magnitudes of two cycles of a sine wave appended with 100 zero-valued samples. Eliminate those zero-valued samples by changing your 'x2 = x'.*k;' command to 'x2 = x(1:100);' to generate EXACTLY two cycles of a sine wave. Then, right after the 'fft' command, plot using 'plot(abs(X2), 'bo')' to see two nonzero spectral magnitude samples. Carl, continue your software modeling. That's a super-good way to learn.